# Naming an output file from a user entered string

Tags: c++, file-io, io

This is my first project in C++. I took a course using C previously and file I/O seems to differ a little.

The project requires the user to enter a name for saving the output file.

I know I should use ofstream which should look like this:

```
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("example.txt");
myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
myfile.close();
```

I've bolded the snippet that's causing confusion.
How can I name the file from a string entered by the user?
*Note, C type string, so an array of characters.
#include < string > is not allowed

Comment: Use a variable instead of a constant string. E.g. `std::string name; cin >> name; std::ofstream myfile(name.c_str());` (As the file name is expected as `const char*` the `name.c_str()` conversion is used to allow usage of `std::string` which is more convenient than a `char []` (of what size) in this case.)

Comment: Note that we should prefer passing file name and opening file through constructor, not `.open()`; and closing file through destructor, not `.close()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my other answer has got a negative vote, here's another solution without `#include <string>`

You can just save the input from the user in a temporary char array and then save it to a string variable `std::string`.

Includes that are necessary:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
```

Saving an input from an user into a char array:

```
char input[260];
cin >> input;
```

To then save it in a string variable just do this:

```
string filename = input;
```

To open a file stream you'll need to use `std::ofstream`. Please keep in mind, that the file is created in the same folder as the project/application is.

```
std::ofstream outfile (filename + "." + "file extension");
```

And as you already know this `outfile.open();` opens the file.

With `outfile << "hello";` you can write into the file.

To close the file, use `outfile.close();` to close the file.

Here you have a little example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    char input[260];
    cin >> input;
    string filename = input;
    ofstream outfile(filename + "." + "txt");
    outfile << "hello";
    outfile.close();
}
```

I hope this helps.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string path;
string name;
string h_path;
string text;

void create() {
    ofstream file(h_path, ios::app);
    if (!file.fail()) {
        file << text;
        file.close();
    }
}

int main() {
    cout << "please enter path(c:\\folder\): ";
    cin >> path;
    cin.ignore();
    path = path + "/";
    cout << "please enter the name of the file (test.txt): ";

getline(cin, name);
    cout << "content of the file: ";
    getline(cin, text);
    h_path = path + name;
    create();
    cout << "new file created";
    cout << h_path;
}
```

Comment: A limitation of the project is the inclusion of <string> is not allowed. I will edit original post.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string fileName;
    cin >> fileName;
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open(fileName);
    myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
    myfile.close();
}
```